# Infinispan: how to invoke EntryProcessor asynchronous?

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan, jcache

Does Infinispan provide this kind functionality similar like Hazelcast([IMap#submitToKey](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#submitToKey(K,%20com.hazelcast.map.EntryProcessor))) or Ignite([IgniteCache#invokeAsync](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#invokeAsync(K,%20javax.cache.processor.EntryProcessor,%20java.lang.Object...)))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does - through [Functional API](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#functional_map_api). Also note the other ways to [execute code in the grid](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#executing_code_in_the_grid).

Comment: Thanks [Read-Write Map API](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#read_write_map_api) looks close to my needs.